# What is the best way to organise the /var/www directory?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I will soon be hosting around one hundred sites on a LAMP stack. I need to be able to keep my `/var/www` directory organised and scalable. What is the best way to organise this directory?

Here are some of the methods I've seen so far.

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomain/httpdocs/index.html
/var/www/subdomain.example.com/ht_docs/index.html
/var/www/sites/subdomain.example.com/index.html
```

Are there any recommended practices? What's your preferred method?

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer using /srv, but I tend to organise as follows:

```
/srv/<customer name>/<application name>/webroot/
/srv/<customer name>/<application name>/approot/
/srv/<customer name>/<application name>/logs/
```

So

```
/srv/tomoconnor/homesite/webroot/index.html
/srv/tomoconnor/homesite/approot/lib/special.py
/srv/tomoconnor/homesite/logs/access.log
```

Might be how it's laid out. (It's not).

There's not really any hard requirement for how you should lay it out, as long as it's compliant with the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).